# Как отправить видео с YouTube в aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

есть код:

```py
elif '/video' in ms.text:
    print('hello')
    await bot.send_video(
        chat_id=ms.from_user.id,
        video='https://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxs',
        caption='С новым годом!⛄'
    )
```

но он выдает ошибку:

```py
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.InvalidHTTPUrlContent: Failed to get http url content
```

как отправить видео по ссылке в aiogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте отправить обычное сообщение с двойной (что бы было видео) ссылкой -

```
elif '/video' in ms.text:
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "С новым годом!⛄ 
    \nhttps://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxshttps://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxs")
```

Результат -
[image: результат]

Comment: Интересно, а почему ютуб схавал "странную" ссылку? :) Или у него id видео всегда одной длины и он просто из ссылки брал первые n-символов

Comment: Я думаю это не ютуб, а телеграм)

Comment: Ссылка `https://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxshttps://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxs` нормально открывается браузером и разворачивается в `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPhOGiyvwxs`, так что ютуб точно причем :) Возможно и телеграм что-то намутили в своем парсере

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать это не как видео (`video='https://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxs'`), а как ссылку - `url='https://youtu.be/nPhOGiyvwxs'`

Comment: не работает, есть другой способ?

Comment: Есть ещё один вариант) Сейчас добавлю